# issue with drawing two CGMutablePathRef

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

So I can't seem to be able to draw 2 CGMutablePathRef. Here's the code:

```
CGRect mainRect = CGRectMake(2, 2, rect.size.width-4, 210);
    CGMutablePathRef mainPathRef = createRoundedRectForRect(mainRect, 4);

    if (self.imageExists_){

        [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] set];

        CGContextAddPath(context, mainPathRef);
        CGContextClip(context);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainRect.size);

        //need to flip the images to that it is drawn appropriately as CALayer uses a different coordinate system
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, 210);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, mainRect, self.highlightItem_.highlightStoryImage.CGImage);

        UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [scaledImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

this draws the image just fine on the path I specified, clipped. But then I want to draw another rounded rect below it, so I did:

```
 [[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0] set];

     CGFloat colors [] = {
     0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 1.0,
     0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 1.0
     };

     CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
     CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, NULL, 2);
     CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

     CGContextSaveGState(context);

     CGRect commentRect = CGRectMake(2, 215, rect.size.width-4, rect.size.height - 215);
     CGMutablePathRef pathRef = createRoundedRectForRect(commentRect, 3);

     CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
     CGContextClip(context);

     CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(commentRect), CGRectGetMinY(commentRect));
     CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(commentRect), CGRectGetMaxY(commentRect));

     CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
     CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

     CGContextRestoreGState(context);

     CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
     CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work? How? What do you get?

Comment: I am not seeing the 2nd rounded path. Only seeing the first one. Actually when i remove the image drawing it worked. Wonder why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've clipped the drawing to the first rect, but haven't reset the clipping path before drawing the second time. You need to save the graphics state before the first clipping path is invoked, I believe.

Your first snippet should look something like this:

```
CGContextSaveGState(...);
CGContextAddPath(...);
CGContextClip(...);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(...);
... rest of your drawing code...
CGContextRestoreGState(...);
```

and then the second code snippet.

Comment: at which line are you referring to??

Comment: I updated the answer above with some code to show what I meant.